# Anular 4 real time graph

Tags: angular, livecharts

i am looking forward for angular 4 line graph which accepts x axis as timestamp/Some time string from the server that is been fetched. And i want y axis as my value fetched from the serve to plot it.

Can some one help me out to solve my issue. It should like real graph where x axis should have 10 pints but values should be changed according to time

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [d3](https://d3js.org/); it is created specially for this purpose.

Also, please check the [user's guide for stack overlow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) about how to ask questions here. This site is not for writing your code for free, but a help center on exact questions, problems.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/) you will find different types of line charts over here.

Also you can find demo on this link [line chart](https://stackblitz.com/edit/line-chart)